# Player double jumps immediately with a single press when using new Input System

Tags: unity, c#, input, jumping

I am making a 2.5D runner game and I want to switch my input from the legacy Input Manager to Unity's new Input System package.

I am facing a problem when I'm trying to implement the double jump when the player presses space twice. With the legacy Input Manager, there was `bool CanDoubleJump` which is true when the player is grounded, for double jump I was checking if `CanDoubleJump` is true and player pressed jump. It was working perfectly fine. Here's is the code.

````cs
using UnityEngine;

namespace EndlessRunning
{
    [CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "New Object", menuName = "ScriptableObject/Ability/DoubleJump")]
    public class DoubleJump : ScriptableObjectData
    {
        [SerializeField]
        private bool CanDoubleJump = true;

        public override void OnEnter(PlayerStateBase playerStateBase, Animator animator, AnimatorStateInfo stateInfo)
        {

        }
        public override void OnUpdate(PlayerStateBase playerStateBase, Animator animator, AnimatorStateInfo stateInfo)
        {

            //if (playerStateBase.characterControl.DoubleJump)
            //{
            //    animator.SetBool(HashManger.Instance.DicMainParameters[AnimatorParameters.DoubleJump], true);
            //    playerStateBase.characterControl.CanDoubleJump = false;
            //}

            if (playerStateBase.characterControl.Grounded)
            {
                CanDoubleJump = true;
            }
            else
            {
                if (CanDoubleJump && playerStateBase.characterControl.Jump)
                {
                    animator.SetBool(HashManger.Instance.DicMainParameters[AnimatorParameters.DoubleJump], true);
                    CanDoubleJump = false;
                }
            }
        }

        public override void OnExit(PlayerStateBase playerStateBase, Animator animator, AnimatorStateInfo stateInfo)
        {
        }
    }
}
``|

I tried to do the same thing with the new Input System, but it is not working: the character goes into double jump even if space is pressed only once. I am using Unity events for calling the function, and `CandoubleJump` is defined in character control, working the same way. 

**Code** 

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

namespace EndlessRunning
{
    public class PlayerInputController : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [SerializeField]
        private CharacterControl control;
        public PlayerInput inputComp;

        private void Awake()
        {

            inputComp = GetComponent<PlayerInput>();
            control = GetComponent<CharacterControl>();
        }

        private void Update()
        {
            //RunModInput() Legacy;
        }

        //input system new
        public void JumpMethod(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
        {
            if (context.performed)
            {
                if (!control.StartRun)
                {
                    control.StartRun = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    control.Jump = true;
                }

                if (control.CanDoubleJump && control.Jump)
                {
                    control.DoubleJump = true;
                    control.CanDoubleJump = false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                control.Jump = false;
                control.DoubleJump = false;
            }
        }


        #region Run Mod Input legacy
        //private void RunModInput()
        //{
        //    if (InputManger.Instance.StartRun)
        //    {
        //        control.StartRun = true;
        //    }
        //    else
        //    {
        //        control.StartRun = false;
        //    }
        //    if (InputManger.Instance.Jump)
        //    {
        //        control.Jump = true;
        //    }
        //    else
        //    {
        //        control.Jump = false;
        //    }
        //    if (InputManger.Instance.Slide)
        //    {
        //        control.Slide = true;
        //    }
        //    else
        //    {
        //        control.Slide = false;
        //    }
        //    if (InputManger.Instance.Dash)
        //    {
        //        control.Dash = true;
        //    }
        //    else
        //    {
        //        control.Dash = false;
        //    }
        //}
        #endregion
    }
}
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**figured out the solution: updated code** i also had to check that the player must not be grounded for the double jump to work

```
  public void JumpInput(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
    {
        if (context.performed)
        {
            if (!control.StartRun)
            {
                control.StartRun = true;
            }
            else
            {
                control.Jump = true;

                if (!control.Grounded && control.CanDoubleJump && control.Jump)
                {
                    control.DoubleJump = true;
                    control.CanDoubleJump = false;
                }
            }

        }
        else
        {
            control.Jump = false;
            control.DoubleJump = false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If `control.StartRun == false` and `control.CanDoubleJump == true` you are double-jumping right after jumping.

```csharp
//...
            else
            {
                control.Jump = true;
            }

            if (control.CanDoubleJump && control.Jump)
            {
                control.DoubleJump = true;
                control.CanDoubleJump = false;
            }
//...
```

Comment: I think you found the problem. But can you also show the question author a solution for it?

Comment: nah i also had to check ground for double jump player must be not grounded